seek vs look for a job
I'd thought they both meant the same thing (except that seek is a little more formal), but I was told that "seek a job" is not as good as "look for a job". Is this a matter of preference or do all native speakers feel the same way?

It is true that people who are financially stable should seek a job they thoroughly enjoy.


seek seems fine to me.  If you were told this,  then go ask the person who told you.

Yes, I've emailed him and am waiting for his response, but sometimes the answer might be a matter of opinion, in which case I need responses from different people to draw a conclusion.

My guess would be that it is the formality, with "seek" being thought to be incongruent with the tone and formality of the rest of the sentence.  but like i said, it seems fine to me.

In the UK, the State benefit which may be paid to people who are not working is called Jobseeker's Allowance.  It used to be called 'Unemployment Benefit' but I think the change was intended to focus a recipient's mind on looking for work rather than being (and possibly remaining) unemployed.

Please note that there are verb phrase idioms which are used much more frequently than "to look for a job" and "to seek a job." They are "to get a job" and "to find a job."
In the context of a job hunt, they are used with "to try" so that their constructions are "[to try] to get a job" and "[to try] to find a job."
"To find a job" or "[to try] to find a job" is standard usage in all contexts. "To get a job" or "[to try] to get a job" is very informal.

I am trying to find a job. She was trying to get a job. He had been trying to find a job.


The elephants tried to find jobs at the circus; they tried to get jobs at the zoo; they finally tried to find jobs at the movie studio, where they tried to get jobs acting as friendly pachyderms.


Both look for a job and seek a job are valid
phrases.  The usage comparison of the various inflected forms is shown on the chart.
Ngram
Edit
The direct comparison shows that look for a job is much more common than seek a job.
All four senses in Collins Dictionary state formal in their illustrations, like this one:

[formal] They have had to seek work as labourers.

Collins Dictionary

Seek is not incorrect, it's just very formal.
You probably wouldn't hear it in spoken American English, but someone might write it that way.
